# USB to HDMI converter

Tags: usb, hdmi

I am in need of an USB to HDMI converter. My pc does not have a HDMI socket and I still want to connect it to my smartTV to copy my desktop on the TV.

I kept searching for these kind of devices but a lot of questions come to mind:

1. I came across a lot of these kind of cables
   [image: micro USB cable]
   saying 'micro USB to HDMI'. Does this just simply work if I only plug in the USB part in my desktop (because the micro USB is of no use to me).
2. I don't know what versions of USB I have in my PC (its a pretty old PC but I dont know if its 2.0 or lower) does this matter? Does a USB 3.0 (or 2.0) to HDMI converter work on lower USB versions too?
3. Does sound also get transmitted?

I am using Windows XP if this is important.

Extra: (even though this website is in Dutch), why is this USB 3.0 version
[image: 3.0]
significantly cheaper than this USB 2.0 version?
[image: 2.0]
And are these the things I need in case the ones I mentioned in point 1 are not what I need?

Comment: Since I do not have enough reputation to post more than 2 links, this is the link for the 2.0 one I mentioned 
 (http://www.allekabels.nl/hdmi-omvormer/1792/1163653/usb-20-naar-hdmi-adapter.html)

Comment: `De geheel nieuwe USB2 naar HDMI omvormer ` on a webpage discussing their USB 3 product does not insprire confidence.

Comment: What video ports does your gou have? Your not going to be able pass audio without an hdmi port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB to HDMI converters perse do not exist. However what does exists are graphics cards with a HDMI output which connect to your computer via an USB interface.

This is different in such a way that it does not translate USB to HDMI. (This might seem trivial, but it is technically quite different).

> I don not know what versions of USB I have in my PC (its a pretty old PC but I
>   do not know if its 2.0 or lower) does this matter?

yes, it matters. Generating anything but static video requires enough bandwidth. Anything will do if you just want to open an excel sheet and keep it open 24/7 (e.g. display a roster or a phone book on a second monitor). However when you change the screens contents new data must be sent to the graphics card. This requires significant bandwidth.

USB 2 might be enough to scroll though PDF pages, spreadsheets etc, but not enough to watch a movie on or to game on.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, so I will need USB 3.0 if I want to watch movies on this smartTV? If it's only necessary for powerpoints etc, can you suggest me some solutions for my case? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You want USB3, thunderbolt or expresscard for watching movies. USB2 may work fine it your power points are static (e.g. just show a page with bullet points. Talk/present or read. Change to the next page. But might be to slow if you have ppts full of animations).

Comment: Will a cable like this http://www.tvaudio.nl/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/448x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/7/1/7171000596_0.jpg work if only the USB part is connected?

Comment: Possibly not. That cable hold active electronics which need power. That power is often supplied by the USB bus. Many devices require more power than a single USB bus can provide and one of the workarounds for that is to try to draw power from multiple USB ports. Thus it **could** be that you need both cables. (An other option is that one is enouh for this specific device and that the two cables are just user friendly). To be sure read the devices manual.